# SQL server R2 enterprise download?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I cannot find the link for this download. SQL server R2 enterprise. I don't need service pack 1, I need R2 enterprise first then i can upgrade to SP1. My current version is SQL server 2008 enterprise.

I cannot find anywhere to download this.

Comment: How did you buy your SQL Server 2008 R2 license? I'm pretty sure whichever seller sold you the license also give you the media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the express version and an evaluation version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/search.aspx?q=sql%20server%202008%20r2&fs=producttype~%255eApplication%2524&p=0&r=10&t=&s=price~Descending), but you can't download the enterprise version that easy. You can do that, if you purchased the product - then you will recieve access to download the file.

Comment: If i have SQL server 2008 enterprise installed, When I upgrade can I use the standard edition? Or i need to install the enterprise edition?

Comment: Haven't tried, but when you upgrade, i'm pretty sure you need to take the same version

Comment: @stb: Please update the link. This link has been broken

Answer (score 0):

its paid

[SQL-Server-2008-R2-Enterprise-Edition](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Enterprise-Edition-25-Client-Access-Licenses/productID.221628500)